# How to use listener method in ListView?

Tags: android

I have a ListView, my List View contains ImageView, two TextViews. If we click ImageView, image will be changed. If we click Textview Popup will be visible. Just I am using ListView.

If we click on ImageView, image is changing and popup also visible. I used following code:

```
   mListPreview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                mRelChangeQuantityPopup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

In my Adapter class used following code:

```
holder.mImgPreviewCheck.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        
            
                if (event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN){
                    
                  if(mClickedListFlag==0){
                         holder.mImgPreviewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.app21_bluecheck_nor);
                         mClickedListFlag=1;            
                  }
                  else{
                         holder.mImgPreviewCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.app21_bluechec);
                         mClickedListFlag=0;
                  }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: If we click Image,only will be change and popup will not be visible.Here we click on Image,images are changing and also popup raising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OnClick()` for **ImageView** and **TextView** inside your Adapter `getView()` method instead of `setOnItemClickListener()` method.